# JPA allocationSize not working with PostgreSQL Sequence

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Netbeans 8.0.2 (standard modules)

Eclipselink (JPA 2.1) (default)

Glassfish 4.0  (standard modules)

PostgreSQL 9.4 (under win7x64)

CustomerContact.class:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="customerContactSequence", sequenceName="customer_contact_seq", allocationSize=356, initialValue=2345)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="customerContactSequence")
private Long id;
```

JPA/PostgreSQL assign id to row with correct initialValue, but incorrect allocationSize. Id increments by 1, not 356. I've tried to select nextval from pgAdmin (value is correct) and from em.createNativeQuery (value is correct), but in em.persist id is wrong. I've traced eclipselink, see attachment.

[entry 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzyTY.jpg)

[entry 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9XNF.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean with value is correct? You mean the sequence does increment by 365? When you use allocationsize this is to be expected, JPA implementation will fill in the steps inbetween, therefore reducing the number of sequence accesses in the DB. Not sure what Eclipselink does, Hibernate at least uses a HoLo algorithm: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier (search SEQ_GEN)

Comment: Did you create the tables yourself, or use EclipseLink to generate them? If you created them yourself, you are responsible for ensuring that the sequence increment is the same as the `allocationSize` declared in the `SequenceGenerator`.

Comment: @eckes Value has correct initialValue, but allocationSize not works.

Comment: @CraigRinger Tables are created by EclipseLink. Sequence increment are correct (in PostgreSQL), sequence works in pgAdmin and eclipselink nativequery, but when eclipselink creates entitites with persist method, entities has ids without correct increment (see attachments above)